# Google Chrome breaks links with z-index: -1

Tags: html, css

So recently I've come across an issue with Chrome in which if I set a z-index of -1 to a `position: relative;` unordered list, the links become unclickable.

See http://jsfiddle.net/raLnx/ in Chrome 20.0.1132.47m for an example.

There is no issue if both `ul` sections are given a positive z-index, but I figured this is either a bug in chrome or there is a better way than setting something `position: relative;` when I don't need to.

The css in question:

```
ul.over {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #DDD;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #AAA;
}

ul.under {
    height: 35px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    background-color: #EEE;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-size: 90%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 5px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That's not a google-chrome specific, that happens on firefox too...

Comment: I was going to suggest is this a bug or is this expected behaviour as essentially you are setting the link to appear below all the other layers

Comment: @silentw does the firefox 3d display shed any light onto where the link appears relative to the body?

Comment: well, according to [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index), you SHOULD be able to do this, so it is legitimately a bug

Comment: @NicholasKing http://i.imgur.com/bChuF.png

Comment: @SandyGifford but is it not still confirming to the specs as its allowed you to place a negative integer on the box(link) its just rendered another transparent element over the top of it.

Comment: i think that is what @silentw image shows

Comment: i believe this http://jsfiddle.net/raLnx/5/ illustrates what is happening with a non negative z-index

Comment: It's not what I expected, seeing as there isn't a div in-between the two elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it happens is because your div #nav is now above your list/links. You will have to remove z-index from your list.

Comment: Could you provide an example on jsfiddle? What I have tried by editing #nav doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, this is what I began with. But unfortunately it hides the bottom border that I was trying to show using z-index.

Comment: How about this http://jsfiddle.net/raLnx/15/ I applied border-top to your second list

Comment: Not the perfect solution but it seems as if there is not a clean way to do what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Just move the bottom position of your subnav to 1px. You can have the border on the bottom of the top nav, and it helps your padding, too.